# Class Library Portable: Unable to load dll

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I am trying to build a Portable class library (for iOS/Android).  In the library, I am trying to make a GET call to an API but I am getting an Aggregate Exception with an inner exception of Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives'.  I thought I had gotten past that by updating the nuget packages but now receive the same error but for NewtonSoft.Json.  How do I resolve these errors.  Below is the code for the API call.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<IPG>> Retrieve(IPG request)
    {
        IResponse result = null;

        var url = "https://someurl.net/";
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/getData");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();

        }
        return result.data;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked in bin folder whether there is System.Net.Http.Primitives dll file with same version in dependentAssembly section in config file

Comment: Yes the dlls are in the bin directory.

Comment: is that dll version same with config file ?

Comment: Yes they are both 4.2.29.0

Comment: I am not sure but you can check with exception, for what version of file it's throwing error?

Comment: The full exception message is?

Comment: {"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"}

Comment: You need to post the entire method call. It sounds like you are using a Task in your portable library and that is why you are getting that error.  If you are you need to return IAsyncResult instead of Task from all public methods in Portable Class libraries.  Oops... Actually I think that's for RuntimeComponents and not Portable Class libraries... Apologies... But that's the first thing in my mind when I saw the error as I've seen similar before myself.

Comment: Can you post the most code or at least the entire method?  I'm a little curious myself and will help you dig.

Comment: I've included the full method

Comment: Once, I got this issue but it was from my build script which has been copying old dll from the folder which I had given path to copy. So, you can search about that dll in your solution folder and check whether there is any old dll present.